# Will humans ever evolve to cope with the rising temperature of our planet?

Tags: evolution, mutations, human-evolution

I am a complete layman of this field(Biology).I went through an article about global temperature rise and i wanted to ask this question.

> Federal science agencies announced Wednesday that 2016 was the warmest year on record, beating the previous record of global temperature set in 2015, which had beat the previous record set in 2014.

[image]

*(As seen in the graph temperature is rising rapidly and will increase even more in the near future.)*

Can we evolve to cope with high temperature?Will we evolve?Is mutation the only answer?

*(Frankly not looking for an answer saying by natural selection,the last thing i want to hear)*

Comment: The graph actually shows that the temperature has risen although over the last few years it is constant. What it does not, and cannot, show is the direction it will take in the future and, if there is a change, how rapidly it will occur.  There may be other reasons for thinking it will change, but as a layman you should learn that it is unscientific to attribute these to the graph you present. This should be evident from the fact that previous downward trends did not continue.

Comment: No, for two reasons.  First, the time scale of human evolution (10K-100K years) is much longer than the time scale of the athropogenic temperature increase (100-1000 years).  Second, if the rise continues, humans will become extinct, along with most multicellular life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A change in temperature of 1 degree, or even 4 degrees, is less than the variation in temperature that is seen between different areas that are inhabited by humans and less than the variation which is seen annually in those areas. Accordingly it seems that humans are already adapted to these differences in temperature and that our response to the temperature changes are more likely to involve habituation and cultural changes in behaviour and technology use than evolutionary change.

Comment: The difficulties for human are not so much a direct effect of the few degrees difference but the effect that temperature will have on ecosystems in general and on our agriculture and its repercussion to us.